# Array of java.lang.reflect.Type is not parsed correctly as a vararg

Tags: java, arrays, jvm, variadic-functions

Here's a really fast example of the problem:

```
Arrays.asList(new Object[]{null})
```

returns a 1 element list where its only value is null, as expected.

```
Arrays.asList(new java.lang.reflect.Type[]{null})
```

return a 1 element list, whose element is an array of Types which in turn has only a null value.

So, it seems that if i pass an array of Type objects it doesn't get interpreted by the JVM as a vargarg and so in this case the asList method creates a list with the whole array as an element.

Comment: Is there some compelling reason not to do List<Type> list = new ArrayList(type); list.add(null)?

Comment: @user714965 That should not make any difference.

Comment: My example is a simplified one. What i'd like to do is use the asList method properly providing an already populated array of instances of Type.

Comment: Can you show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem?

Comment: As it turns out this was a freakout of my debugger. In debugging mode i was getting the results like i described, executing normally i got the expected behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something else is going on...

I wrote the following test:

```
@Test
public void testAsList() {

    List<Object> listO = Arrays.asList(new Object[] { null });
    System.out.println(listO.size());
    System.out.println(listO.get(0) == null);

    List<Type> listT = Arrays.asList(new Type[] { null });
    System.out.println(listT.size());
    System.out.println(listT.get(0) == null);
}
```

I get the following result:

```
1
true
1
true
```

which demonstrates that both calls are behaving the same (giving a list of a single element that is `null`)

Comment: Just done almost exactly the same test myself in JUnit.  Got results as indicated by John B.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a JUnit test method that demonstrates the results John B. describes.  The code does not behave as stated in the original question, and is self-consistant.

```
public void testAsList() {
    List<Object> list1 = Arrays.asList(new Object[]{null});
    assertSize(1, list1);
    assertNull(list1.get(0));
    List<java.lang.reflect.Type> list2 = Arrays.asList(new java.lang.reflect.Type[]{null});
    assertSize(1, list2);
    assertNull(list2.get(0));
}
```

Comment: Apologies, 'testSize()' is a extra assertion method in my own code base (not a standard JUnit one).  But still, you get the idea.